# Advanced eloquent filtering with pivot table

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, filtering

A challenge for the community! I have a map which presents multiple stores. When a user clicks on a store it should load only the **relevant products**. To do this I have four tables (see below).

I am able to bring up the relevant products from the brand **if the user applied a gender filter `$gender`** by using `if(!is_null($gender)) $q->where($gender, '=', 1);`.However, **I would like to be able to present the correct products even if the user did *not* filter**.

The challenge is that **a brand could have products for both men and women, but placed in separate stores** (or in the same store). To track this I have the pivot table named brands_stores.

In short - what I would like add is something like

```
$q->with(['products' => function ($q) use ($product_ids [GENDER(S) FROM PIVOT TABLE]){
    $q->whereIn('gender', [GENDER(S) FROM PIVOT TABLE];
}
```

to the existing query below.

**Query**

```
    // Get stores
    $query = Store::with(['brandsUnfiltered' => function ($q) use ($active, $gender, $product_ids){
        if(!is_null($active)) $q->where('active', '=', 1);  // Active stores
            if(!is_null($gender)) $q->where($gender, '=', 1);   // Gender
            $q->with(['products' => function ($q) use ($product_ids){
                $q->whereIn('id', $product_ids);
                $q->orderBy('brand', 'asc')->orderBy('gender', 'desc')->orderBy('category', 'asc')->orderBy('sub_category', 'asc');
                $q->groupBy('brand', 'name');
                $q->select('id AS product_id', 'name', 'brand', 'price', 'img_link');
                }]);
            }])
            ->whereIn('id', $store_ids)
            ->select('id', 'name', 'lat', 'lng', 'formatted_address AS address', 'street_number', 'route', 'open_monday', 'open_saturday', 'open_sunday', 'close_monday', 'close_saturday', 'close_sunday', 'formatted_phone_number AS phone' );

        $stores = $query->get();
    }
```

**Store model**

```
class Store extends Eloquent {

    public function brandsUnfiltered(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('\App\Brand', 'brands_stores', 'store_id', 'brand_id')
            ->withPivot('active', 'brand_store', 'women', 'men');
    }
}
```

**Stores table**

- id
- name
- ...

**Brands table**

- id
- name
- ...

**Brands_stores table**

- id
- store_id
- brand_id
- women [BOOLEAN]
- men [BOOLEAN]
- ...

**Products table**

- id
- name
- brand
- gender
- ...

**=====EDIT=====**

**PRODUCTS LINKED TO BRANDS WHICH ARE LINKED TO STORES**

Each Product has a Brand column. That Brand column is the same as the Name column in the Brand model. Which Brands and what Products a store carries from that brand are linked through the Brands_Stores TABLE. Logic flow:

- Does the store carry the relevant brand?
- If it does carry the relevant brand - which products (male or female or both?)
- Get the relevant products

**SQL QUERIES**

```
select `brand` from `products` where `name` like '%louboutin%' or `brand` like '%louboutin%' group by `brand`, `name`

select * from `products` where (`brand` in ('Christian Louboutin')) group by `brand`, `name`

select `id` from `brands` where `name` in ('Christian Louboutin')

select `store_id` from `brands_stores` where (`active` = '1' and `brand_id` in ('278'))

select `id`, `name`,  `formatted_phone_number` as `phone` from `stores` where `id` in ('561', '562', '563', '2182')

select `brands`.*, `brands_stores`.`store_id` as `pivot_store_id`, `brands_stores`.`brand_id` as `pivot_brand_id`, `brands_stores`.`active` as `pivot_active`, `brands_stores`.`brand_store` as `pivot_brand_store`, `brands_stores`.`women` as `pivot_women`, `brands_stores`.`men` as `pivot_men`, `brands_stores`.`children` as `pivot_children` from `brands` inner join `brands_stores` on `brands`.`id` = `brands_stores`.`brand_id` where `brands_stores`.`store_id` in ('562', '2182') and `active` = '1'

select `id` as `product_id`, `name`, `brand`, `price`, `img_link` from `products` where `products`.`brand` in ('Christian Louboutin') and `id` in ('6800', '7538', '7612', '7582', '8095', '7104', '8053', '7995', '7115', '7485', '7997', '7866', '7622', '6820', '7682', '8000', '8055', '6838', '7589', '7046', '7232', '6810', '7609', '7429', '7597', '7557', '7593', '7458', '7481', '7572', '7620', '7238', '7537', '6843', '7619', '7598', '8036', '7284', '6956', '7993', '6863', '8039', '7614', '7493', '7315', '7318', '6841', '7509', '7198', '5813', '8203', '7623', '7441', '8096', '7957', '6522', '6850', '8056', '7821', '6753', '6632', '7569', '7994', '7784', '9388', '9431', '9440', '9392', '6348', '6373', '5989', '7339', '7329', '7340', '7502', '7544', '7586', '7636', '7252', '7179', '7564', '6771', '6461', '6554', '6563', '6442', '5756', '5770', '7439', '7373', '7313', '7349', '7293', '7595', '7323', '7565', '8073', '9363', '9411', '5910', '5899', '6136', '5828', '6577', '6601', '7551', '7392', '7543', '7872', '8076', '7517', '7849', '7531', '7602', '7410', '6836', '7401', '6851', '8034') group by `brand`, `name` order by `brand` asc, `gender` desc, `category` asc, `sub_category` asc
```

Comment: a) how does your `product` table fits in your data-model? I cant see a `product_id` connecting it b) please provide MySQL queries, not the creation syntax for it.

Comment: @Benvorth please see updated Question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a user selects a store your want "load only the relevant products".

Lets start by selecting a store:

```
SELECT stores.id 
FROM stores 
WHERE stores.name = 'selectedStoreName';
```

Now we fetch the available brands in this store:

```
SELECT stores.id, brands_store.brand_id
FROM stores 
JOIN brands_store ON stores.id = brands_store.store_id
WHERE stores.name = 'selectedStoreName';
```

Brand names are better than brand-ids:

```
SELECT stores.id, brands_store.brand_id, brands.name
FROM stores 
JOIN brands_store ON stores.id = brands_store.store_id
JOIN brands ON brands_store.brand_id = brands.id
WHERE stores.name = 'selectedStoreName';
```

And finally we fetch all products from the available brands:

```
SELECT stores.id, brands_store.brand_id, brands.name, products.name, products.gender
FROM stores 
JOIN brands_store ON stores.id = brands_store.store_id
JOIN brands ON brands_store.brand_id = brands.id
JOIN products ON brands.name = products.brand_name
WHERE stores.name = 'selectedStoreName';
```

Very clean data architecture by the way...

Comment: Thanks. The challenge is as I said that I would like to do this on multiple stores at once. In other words pre-load the data so when a user clicks on a store no querying to the server is required. Do you know of a way of how to use the pivot_table data as a 'variable'. E.g. if the brands_stores column for Women is 1 (true) but that for Men is 0 (false), then the products selected for that store should only be women products.

Comment: If you want women-only products pre-loaded from all stores just replace the `stores.name` part in the last query by `products.gender = 'women'`

Comment: A long overdue thank you @Benvorth. The tricky part is that the 'gender' information is not the same for all stores. It comes from the pivot table (brands_store). I made a brutal workaround with 3 queries (one for BOTH men and women, one for men, and one for women only) for the stores that match each separately. Not super happy with the elegance, but get's the job done.